# What is a regular expression to ignore matches at the beginning of a line and/or matches that are preceded by ") "?

Tags: regex

I want to get Free Pascal compiler output messages that look like:

```
program.pas(50,10) Hint: Parameter "input" not used
```

but I want to ignore compiler output messages that look like:

```
Hint: Start of reading config file C:\FPC\fpc.cfg
```

I have tried

```
(.*\) Hint\:.*)
```

and

```
(.*\).Hint\:.*)
```

and both appear to match the line that starts with Hint

Comment: Could you be more specific about the context, e.g. what language, what kind of string literal is this in? `\)` *should* be the proper way to escape a parenthesis in most regex flavors I have seen. Are you sure that the backslash isn't interpreted as an escape of an enclosing string literal or something similar? Are you sure that you are applying the regex per-line?

Comment: Which language are you using? Can you provide a sample code? Can you not match the line you don't want and skip it?

Comment: @Luatic This is for an IDE to correctly identify Warning output of the compiler. It is given in a dialog box edit box to the IDE.

Comment: @Krishna This is for an IDE to correctly identify Warning output of the compiler. It is given in a dialog box edit box to the IDE.

Comment: @Mandy8055 Yes, that does work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below regex to achieve your purpose:

```
^.*\(\d+,\d+\) Hint: .*
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`^`** - Represents start of line. You can ignore it as well based on your requirement.
- **`.*`** - Greedily matches 0 or more occurrences of any character except line terminators.
- **`\(\d+,\d+\) Hint: .*`** - matches any string that has a parenthesis(**`\(` escaped**), one or more digits, a comma, one or more digits, closing parenthesis, **" Hint: "**, and any number of any character.

You can find the **[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/4CHe9O/1)**

[image: Image description]